# Is this a Ghc(i) Bug?!, 19 - 1 not equal to 18?

Tags: haskell

please help me understand this:

I want to generate all prime-roots for a "quotient group" (I hope that's "prime Restklassengruppe" in english ;))

```
import Data.List (nub)  
primeroots rclass = filter (\(x,y) -> (18) == y) produceAllCandidates where
  produceAllCandidates = map makeOneCandidate [1..rclass] where
    makeOneCandidate elem = (elem,  (length (nub (map (\x -> (mod (elem ^ x) rclass)) [0..(rclass -1)]))))
```

Then I run this in ghci and get

```
> primeroots 19
> [(2,18),(3,18),(10,18),(13,18),(14,18),(15,18)]
```

but if I change the 18 in the first line to rclass - 1 (which should yield 18, and does this for all but 15 anyways):

```
primeroots rclass = filter (\(x,y) -> (rclass - 1) == y) produceAllCandidates where
```

and run it with the same Argument

```
> primeroots 19
> [(2,18),(3,18),(10,18),(13,18),(14,18)]
```

Why do I get different results when changing 18 to (rclass - 1) when I call it so, that rclass will be 19 (which then should make (rclass -1) 18?!

Thanks in advance

Comment: In the first case the type is `Integral t => t -> [(t, Int)]` and in the second the type is `Int -> [(Int, Int)]`.  I'm not sure what your function is doing, but do you have some integer oveflow occurring somewhere?

Comment: If you replace `(rclass - 1) == y` with `fromIntegral (rclass - 1) == y` it will do what you expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be a matter of types; forcing the output type to be `Int` makes a difference:

```
Prelude Data.List> primeroots 19
[(2,18),(3,18),(10,18),(13,18),(14,18),(15,18)]
Prelude Data.List> primeroots 19 :: [(Int, Int)]
[(2,18),(3,18),(10,18),(13,18),(14,18)]
```

Narrowing it down:

```
Prelude Data.List> let foo rclass elem = map (\x -> (mod (elem ^ x) rclass)) [0..(rclass -1)]
Prelude Data.List> foo (19 :: Int) 15
[1,15,16,12,9,2,11,13,5,18,4,3,7,10,17,8,6,5,9]
Prelude Data.List> foo (19 :: Integer) 15
[1,15,16,12,9,2,11,13,5,18,4,3,7,10,17,8,6,14,1]
```

Note that the last two elements are different. These are formed by `mod (15 ^ 17) 19` and `mod (15 ^ 18) 19`, respectively, which overflow the `Int` type.

To do this correctly for small numbers, write some kind of `powMod` function, or be a bit wasteful and force the type to be `Integer`.